# How to make multiple calls to class methods inline(chain calls)JavaScript es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I try to call methods of class one by one inline and the second method is undefined.

How can I implement this pattern in ES6 class?

```
await new Mail().attachments(files).send()
```

mail.js

```
export class Mail{

    constructor(){
      this.mail =  {
         *********
         ********* 
      };
    }


    attachments(files){
      *********
      ********* 
    }

    async send(){
        try{
            return await sendmail(this.mail, function(err) {
                if(err){
                    return false
                };
                return true;
            });
        }catch(e){
            throw e;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You need to `return this;` at the end of each function if you want to chain them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure `attachments` ends with `return this` in order to chain methods after it:

```js
const sendmail = () => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 1000));
class Mail {
  constructor() {
    this.mail = 'mail';
  }
  attachments(files) {
    console.log('adding attachments');
    return this;
  }
  async send() {
    console.log('sending...');
    return sendmail(this.mail);
  }
}
(async() => {
  console.log('start');
  const files = 'files';
  await new Mail().attachments(files).send()
  console.log('end');
})();
```

Follow that same pattern whenever you want to define a method you want to chain - `return this` at the end in order to return the instantiated object.